# Firebase database always offline, when tested on physical Android device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am building a native Android application in **Android Studio 3**, which makes use of Firebase Database and Firebase Auth. I have tested it on different virtual devices, where everthing works fine:

- Nexus_5X_API_25_x86 with Android 7.1.1
- Pixel with Android 6.0

It also used to work on physical devices. But somehow not anymore. The Firebase Database seems to be **always in offline mode**. I don't get any errors. It's just always offline. I am checking that like this:

```
    val connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected")
    connectedRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean::class.java)!!
            if (connected) {
                println("FIREBASE IS CONNECTED")
            } else {
                println("FIREBASE IS NOT CONNECTED")
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            System.err.println("Listener was cancelled")
        }
    })
```

My app **definitely has internet access** though, because I'm successfully communicating with the YouTube Data API at the same time.

The physical two physical devices I used, have Android 5.0.2 and 6.0.1 installed.

I also restored a version of my old code, from a time it was still working an physical devices but the problem remained. So I guess it has nothing to do with my code.

Is there maybe some common mistake, related to this? If not, can you tell me how I could further investigate the problem? I am really struggling with this and have no idea what to do. I also can't really find any reports of similar issues.

Comment: Are you just checking .info/connected, or have you also tried actually reading and writing the database?

Comment: yes I am also trying to read from the database at this point. But the listener functions attached are never called. Which is the desired behavior, in offline mode, right?

Comment: Turn on debug logging to see what's going on. `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);`

Comment: hey @Niklas have you resolved the issue?? I am facing the same from past two days

Comment: I have no idea really... It just started working again somehow. I didn't analysed the problem any further. I just was glad it was over. This really gave me some headaches... the only thing I remember changing right before it started working again was: I changed the following line in my _app/build.grade_ `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"` to `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"`. Maybe this is some kind of Java7 -> Java8 problem, but I have no idea. I really hope this magically solves your problem too.